# How do I remove the <a> </a> tag without affecting the text?

Tags: javascript, text, document

I try to remove the `<a> </a>` tag to a many link with javascript example:

```
<a href="somelink.com/1"> content1
</a>
<a href="somelink.com/2"> content12
</a>
<a href="somelink.com/3"> content13
</a>
<a href="somelink.com/3"> content14
</a> ........ ect ...
```

so that it remains this way without affecting the text::

```
content1
content2
content3
content4
```

I try to do it with this code but without success:

```
<script>
document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="somelink.com"]').forEach(
  x => a.href = "  "
)
</script>
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: In your lambda function it should be `x => x.href = ""`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You change its [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) to its [`innerHTML`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)The code is below

```js
function removeTags(){
  document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(a => {
    a.outerHTML = a.innerHTML
  })
  console.log(document.body.innerHTML)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="somelink.com/1"> content1</a>
<a href="somelink.com/2"> content12</a>
<a href="somelink.com/3"> content13</a>
<a href="somelink.com/3"> content14</a>
<button onclick="removeTags()">Remove Tags</button>
```

Comment: pretty clever. Simple and straight-forward

Answer (score 0):

I kept it all pure JavaScript as you tagged JS not JQuery. This would get all the `<a>` tags on the page, so would only work if thats what you wanted. Just add this at the end of your page.

```
<script>
//Get all the a tags on the page
var tags = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++)
{
    //Remove the link
    tags[i].href = "";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

These Are the exact results you showed

```js
function removeLinks(align=true){
 var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
  links.forEach(function(item){
   item.href = "#";
    item.style.display="block";
    item.style.textDecoration='none';
    item.style.color='black';
  });
  
  if (align) {
  var counter = 1;
  links.forEach(function(item){
   item.innerHTML = (item.innerHTML).substr(0,8) + counter;
    counter++;
  })
  }
}
removeLinks(align=true);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Link Remover</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="somelink.com/1"> content1
</a>
<a href="somelink.com/2"> content12
</a>
<a href="somelink.com/3"> content13
</a>
<a href="somelink.com/3"> content14
</a>
</body>
</html>
```